# Backbone: Making Collections out of JSON attributes advice, and making things better

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Up until now I've been using `.get()` and `_.clone()` on the array attributes then making my object up before setting the model but this feels completely wrong and I'm not sure how to improve upon this. I feel the array attributes should be transformed into collections but 1`) I'm not sure how to do this and 2) I'm not sure of the real benefits compared to my current approach.` Can anyone help me improve on my approach? Also note, the POST object needs to be created to be sent via AJAX to a non RESTful service

**Example model:**

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "teams": [],
        "ageGroups": [],
        "categories": []
    }
```

**Example of how my data should look when posting back to server**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
  "teams": [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Team One",
        "location": "UK"
    }, {
        "id": 321,
        "name": "Team Two",
        "location": "USA"
    }
  ],
  "ageGroups": ["16", "18", "21"],
  "categories": [
    {
        "id": 45,
        "name": "Category One"
    }, {
        "id": 65,
        "name": "Category Two"
    }
  ]
}
```

**A very stripped down example:**

```
var myView = new View({

        addToCategory: function() {
            var categories = _.clone(this.model.get('categories'));

            // Grab values I need from user input...

            var categoryDetails = {
                "id": userId,
                "name": userName
            };

            this.model.set({
                categories: categoryDetails
            });
        },

        addToAgeGroups: function() {
            var ageGroups = _.clone(this.model.get('ageGroups'));

            // Grab my age group via user input ...

            ageGroups.push(newAgeGroup);

            this.model.set({
                ageGroups: ageGroups
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone (intentionally?) does not handle nested data particularly well.  After some experience I've resisted the urge to make my `Model` have an attribute on it that is a `Collection`, etc.  It generally makes things more confusing for little benefit.

I suggest making your `Model`s smarter to handle the array attributes, moving some of the logic in your `View` into the `Model` itself.  If you really think some parts of your application would like to treat that data as a full-blown `Collection`, have the `Model` handle that internally too.

For instance:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    getCategories: function() {
        if (!this._categoriesCollection) {
            var categories = this.get('categories');
            this._categoriesCollection = new Backbone.Collection(categories);
        }
        return this._categoriesCollection;
    }

    addCategory: function(categoryDetails) {
        var currentCategories = this.getCategories();
        currentCategories.add(categoryDetails);
   }

});
```

Caching the result of `getCategories()` means you can ensure there is only ever one instance of the collection of categories.  You can add more methods to handle the Parent/Child relationship within the Model, making him the sole owner of that data.

Handling how to POST the data to server seems like a separate question, but generally I've overridden the `Model.sync()` method to do that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try implementing what you've said! May have some more questions when I'm done!